# how to restart a web after re-starting a deallocated Azure Windows VM

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, visual-studio, azure-virtual-machine

I deallocated my Azure Windows server VM last year to save money.
Just re-allocated and restarted it.
Can log in OK.

But when I try to browse my web hosted by the VM, from public Internet I get: 
"This page can’t be displayed"

How do I re-start my .NET web?  (VisualBasic web app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I known, if you shut down/stop your VM by Azure Portal, then the IP (public and internal IPs) addresses that were assigned to your Azure VM would be released as follows:

**Virtual machines (classic)**

[image]

**Virtual machines**

[image]

[image]

As this [blog](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/gbanin/2015/04/22/difference-between-the-states-of-azure-virtual-machines-stopped-and-stopped-deallocated/) mentioned that:

> Note that the IP addresses were excluded (internal and public), if you do not book a public IP (maximum of 5 per signature), you may notice that you have a web site or application on this machine, **the web site / application will be unavailable and when turning it back as a new public IP will be provisioned**. You have to do a DNS entry manually if you are accessing by a proper name.

I have tried to restart my VMs and wait for a while, then I could access my default website. Additionally, you could try to remote to your VM and check your app. Also, please try to check your [inbound network traffic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-classic-setup-endpoints).

Comment: Thanks, indeed it changed.  But I cannot browse to my Azure VM > IIS > my web either, so that problems needs to be fixed first.